# Spring don't work on war deployed with Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a rare problem, at least for me.

I have a project built in Java. Using Maven and Spring MVC. I define a couple of controllers to redirect between pages (.JSP).
I deploy my WAR project on Tomcat webapps folder. And everything seems fine.

Now when I access to the app from the server local IP (192.168...), everything works.
But, when I access from public IP, the only thing I get is the folders of the project, it's like the context configuration of Spring and controllers doesn't work.
Of course, I can to navigate to each page with the complete URL.

Already checked that both directions also point in the same folder.

Thanks in advance.

### EDITED

I want to say that I configure apache and tomcat connector. So When I enter to my local IP with the :8080, my app works fine. But when I enter without it, I see the list of folders.

### EDITED 2

My web server is Apache.
And my connector configuration is:

```
workers.properties:
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009

/etc/apache2/mods-available/tomcat_connector.conf:
<IfModule jk_module>
    # Tomcat Connector custom properties
    JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
    JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/jk.log
    JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.shm
    JkLogLevel error
    JkMount /manager/* worker1
    JkMount /host-manager/* worker1
</IfModule>
```

And the only thing that I add to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default is:

```
JkMountCopy On
```

I get some information from this tutorial:

http://blog.sourcerebels.com/post/28254180614/usar-apache-como-frontal-de-tomcat-en-ubuntu-server

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing here, so apologies if I'm wrong. It sounds like your public IP is being served by a web server and just retruning a directory listing. If you are using a web server you will need to set up a connector between it and tomcat. For example using apache you would use the apache tomcat connector

Comment: Yes I done that, so I can enter to the app with 192.168..:8080 and without the :8080. But when I enter with the :8080 my app works, and when I enter without it I see the list of folders

Comment: Could you include your connector configuration?

Comment: Tomcat is responding to 8080, your webserver is responding to port 80 and listing the files. As @Bart has implied. it's a configuration problem. What is your web server and the configuration to connect to tomcat?